# Matlab print figure in horizontal

Tags: matlab, figure

I am having a small issue with printing Matlab figure into the size I preferred. The current figure I can get is shown on the top and I want to get the figure as the bottom. I used the code from Matlab help to minimize the white space.

Thank You.

Your kindness help is appreciated.

```
ax = gca; 
outerpos = ax.OuterPosition;
ti = ax.TightInset; 
left = outerpos(1) + ti(1);
bottom = outerpos(2) + ti(2);
ax_width = outerpos(3) - ti(1) - ti(3);
ax_height = outerpos(4) - ti(2) - ti(4);
ax.Position = [left bottom ax_width ax_height];
set(gca,'YTick',[0:1:4])
set(gca,'XTick',[0:2:20])
set(gca,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','on')
set(gca,'TickLength',[0.015 0.01])
set(gca,'FontSize',12)
set(gca,'FontName','Times New Roman')
set(gca,'layer','top')
set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer');
```

[image: Figure got white space at the top and bottom]

[image: Figure got minimum white space at the top and bottom]

Comment: Top and bottom figures seems to be equals to my eyes

Comment: Ya, it is equal, but the figure on top got white space, but the bottom is without white space. I wanted to remove the white space so that the printed figure will be maximized.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the MATLAB file exchange which may satisfy your needs: [`tightfig`](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34055-tightfig-hfig). It automatically reduces the maximum of whitespace possible.

Compare this (just running your code):

[image]

to this (just running your code with `tightfig`

```
% Your code example from above (all but last two lines skipped) ...
set(gca,'layer','top')
set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer'); 
tightfig;      % Calling tightfig function
```

[image]

(right click the figures and "open in new tab" to see the difference)